# Android - Issue between Threads (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, android, networking

I've written an Android-App, thats checks the Internet-Connections to Google(over a Socket, i guess)! When I got the answer from my Networking-Thread(the checking method), i try to update my textview with setText, but i get a nullpointerexception! It might be a quiet easy bug in my code, but i simply don't get it.

Here's my MainActivity:

```
package at.springsits.michi.hostchecker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView connection_internet;
    Button pingbutton;
    Networking net;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        connection_internet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connection);
        pingbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ping_button);
        pingbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            `enter code here`net.connectionToGoogle = Networking.testPingToGoogle();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        connection_internet.setText(String
                                .valueOf(net.connectionToGoogle));
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
06-26 16:38:00.030: D/libEGL(2756): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
06-26 16:38:00.030: D/libEGL(2756): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
06-26 16:38:00.030: D/libEGL(2756): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
06-26 16:38:00.030: I/Adreno200-EGL(2756): <eglInitialize:269>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic AU_full_mako_PARTNER-ANDROID/JB-MR1-DEV_CL2961380_release_AU (CL2961380)
06-26 16:38:00.030: I/Adreno200-EGL(2756): Build Date: 12/10/12 Mon
06-26 16:38:00.030: I/Adreno200-EGL(2756): Local Branch: 
06-26 16:38:00.030: I/Adreno200-EGL(2756): Remote Branch: m/partner-android/jb-mr1-dev
06-26 16:38:00.030: I/Adreno200-EGL(2756): Local Patches: NONE
06-26 16:38:00.030: I/Adreno200-EGL(2756): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
06-26 16:38:00.070: D/OpenGLRenderer(2756): Enabling debug mode 0
06-26 16:38:03.414: W/dalvikvm(2756): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bf9930)
06-26 16:38:03.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2756): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6549
06-26 16:38:03.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2756): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 16:38:03.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2756):     at at.springsits.michi.hostchecker.Main$1.run(Main.java:37)
06-26 16:38:03.414: E/AndroidRuntime(2756):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Post the logcat so we know what is `null`

Comment: `net` is null, I think. `Networking net` then `net.connectionToGoogle = Networking.testPingToGoogle()`.

Comment: i guess i need a Networking net = new Networking() somewhere ?

Comment: Yes - is this your own class? Anyway I've posted an answer.

Comment: yes, it is. I can't believe that i was too dump to see that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`net` is null. You are trying to access one of its fields before it's been instantiated.

You declare it up here:

```
Networking net
```

Then try and access it in the `onClick()`

```
net.connectionToGoogle = Networking.testPingToGoogle()
```

But at this stage `net` is `null`. Instantiate it in your `onCreate()` or similar before you try to use it:

```
net = new Networking();
```